# Одна база данных на нескольких сайтах под управлением Joomla.

Tags: joomla, mysql

Вы не могли бы мне помочь(пожалуйста) 
У меня случилось что то ужасное: Я на свою голову взялась помочь своему товарищу. В общем он нашел для себя не плохой шаблон Joomla и решил его примерить на свой уже готовый сайт - у него ничего не вышло и тогда он обратился ко мне (к дуре!). В общем шаблон установить не получилось и у меня - тогда я решила что можно будет просто на виртуальном хосте (Денвер) сделать еще один сайт с его шаблоном этому новому сайту присвоить временно базу данных от его работающего сайта, так и сделала. Указала на новом сайте, в настройках joomla базу данных от старого, уже готового сайта (я просто хотела взглянуть на этот шаблон в полной красе - пустым, незаполненным он был вообще не какой). Ну а после всей этой процедуры взглянула на результат - новый сайт остался таким же пустым. Решила ну что теперь поделать, не вышло так не вышло. Через какое то время решила войти в админку джумлы на старом сайте и вот тогда начались первые проблемы: Войти я не смогла, была ошибка ввода пароля - ввела в адресную строку имя старого сайта, а он почему то был абсолютно пустым, не было не меню ни текстовой информации - только шапка и кнопка номе (какой это ужас..). Старый сайт был готов, заполнялся почти три месяца - а теперь я его убила.. Проблему нужно было решать. Мне показалось что если я удалю джумлу с этим новым (проклятым) шаблоном проблема решится. Удалила папку с новым сайтом, попыталась сново войти в админку сайта - а он зараза все также меня не впускает. Я ввела логин и пароль от уже удаленного сайта и "о чудо!" и попала в админку, но там все было не так как до всех этих проблем - там также пропало все, не было ни статей, ни разделов, ни модулей. Зашла в раздел общие настройки чтоб убедиться что там указанна старая база данных - там все было верно. 
Наверное меня убъют.. ( 
Что мне делать - как мне вернуть базу данных Помоги пожалуйста Я не нашла в интернете решения от подобных проблем. Надежда на вас и еще на одного человека, но я пока не могу с ним связаться. Помогите люди добрые.

Comment: Стоп, я запуталась. А бд где висела? А лучше скиньте на darikapiterski@mail.ru все данные, попробую помочь.
На будущее, делайте дамп базы перед подобными экспериметами.

Answer (score 1):

Напишите свою историю в поддержку хостинга и попросите дамп сайта за вчера-позавчера, 99% что он сохранен (иначе меняем хостера на будущее). Обязательно укажите, что нужен дамп как базы данных, так и файлов. Когда получите - заливайте файлы, обновляйте бд и сайт станет вчерашним. По восстановлению БД mysql очень много в гугле.

Итак, вам сказочно повезло =) Смотрим ссылки:

- [раз](http://joomla-support.ru/printthread.php?s=9dcf7b2b1949938dcca2cbc715d68f64&t=10664)
- [два](http://joomlaforum.ru/index.php?topic=164100.msg886081)

И действуем по любому предложенному способу. phpMyAdmin в денвере находится по адресу `http://localhost/Tools/phpMyAdmin`

*ЗЫ: зато вы на себе поняли, зачем делаются полные бэкапы баз данных)*

Comment: Так это все дело у меня на локальной машин

Comment: Оу) Как бы не пришлось восстановлением данных пользоваться. Джумла какой версии? Префиксы таблиц какие у старого и "нового"(одинаковые или нет)? + найдите phpmyadmin (в денвере он есть) и попробуйте оттуда посмотреть, что у вас в базе осталось. По большей части интересует, одна ли у вас таблица {PREFIX}_content и что у нее внутри. А, о, посмотрите в базе, нет ли таблиц 'bak_....', если есть, они вас и спасут)

Comment: И стоп, вы уверены, что работающий сайт друга у вас на локальной машине?..

Comment: Версия Джумлы 1.5.14
Не знаю на счет таблиц, Префикс базы данных у старого jos_ и у нового (который я удалила) jos_
У меня есть доступ к базе данных - в ней есть таблицы 'bak_....
только я вот не пойму - у меня phpmyadmin в денвере три файла: phpmyadmin.css.php , phpMyAdmin.spec , phpMyAdmin-http.conf

Comment: оба сайта были на локалбной машине

Comment: Обновил ответ.